# sql injection list databases syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I'm learning SQL injection in one of my security classes and this is for an extra credit assignment on a project site the professor created himself. I want to list all the databases but I'm having some trouble with the syntax. I have tested that this is sql injection vulnerable, so then I tried

```
';show databases;--
```

in the username input field. but then I got an error saying

```
syntax error near 'show databases;--' and password=';show databases;--' at line 1
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: SQL injection only really happens when whatever to which you are passing the SQL fragment is then altering it, rather than using it directly.  You need to show us how the above fragment is being used (if not, then you are just making blind guesses).

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear? I don't quite understand...@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: so I can see in my sqlmap that there are 4 databases and I used 
```
show databases;
```
to achieve this. I thought I could just use the same query statement in my sql injection.

Comment: *I thought I could just use the same query statement in my sql injection.* Well, I guess, now you know you can't. You did nothing wrong, except maybe expecting that every sql injection works by just entering the code you want to execute. Just find a different way to abuse this. Is your task to list the databases? The error message looks more like you are supposed to bypass some authentication, e.g. login without a valid password or as an admin.